# Adding new criteria to my formula

Tags: excel

I have formula from that, I am getting output, now I wanted to add one more criteria,

```
=SUM(SUMIF('Data '!$C$2:$C$410,IF(H7=Translation!$A$2:$A$27,Translation!$C$2:$C$27),'Data '!$J$2:$J$410)*COUNTIF(H7,Translation!$A$2:$A$27)*Translation!$E$2:$E$27)
```

I wanted to show only last 30 days data, date is in Data sheet column number I.

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: Can you please accept my answer giving that formula at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22422418/calculating-sum-based-on-multiple-sheets/22425320#22425320

Comment: I don't know, how to accept in Stackoverflow? and how to make solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do that you can change the `SUMIF` to a `SUMIFS` function and include the date criteria within that `SUMIFS`, i.e. with dates in column I this will only cover the last 30 days including today

`=SUM(SUMIFS('Data '!$J$2:$J$410,'Data '!$C$2:$C$410,IF(H7=Translation!$A$2:$A$27,Translation!$C$2:$C$27),'Data '!$I$2:$I$410,">"&TODAY()-30,'Data '!$I$2:$I$410,"<="&TODAY())*COUNTIF(H7,Translation!$A$2:$A$27)*Translation!$E$2:$E$27)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> as before

`SUMIFS` requires `Excel 2007` or later